# Django pagination show me all objects beginning with second page

Tags: django

I made pagination in the standard way, but from the second page on the page all the objects are visible. All subsequent pages contain the same data.
If I return to page one from any other page, then I can see all existing objects on it

**views.py**

```
def viewtrainers(request, slug):
    trainers_list = Profile.objects.filter(city__slug = slug)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    paginator = Paginator(trainers_list, 10)
    try:
        trainers = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        trainers = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        trainers = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render(request, "trainers.html", {'trainers':trainers})
```

template.html

```
{% if trainers.has_other_pages %}
  <ul class="pagination justify-content-center" style="margin:20px 0">
    {% if trainers.has_previous %}
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ trainers.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="page-item disabled"><span class="page-link" >&laquo;</span></li>
    {% endif %}
    {% for i in trainers.paginator.page_range %}
      {% if trainers.number == i %}
        <li class="page-item active"><span class="page-link">{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
      {% else %}
        <li><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% if trainers.has_next %}
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ trainers.next_page_number }}">&raquo;</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="page-item disabled"><span class="page-link" >&raquo;</span></li>
    {% endif %}
  </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pagination works when you sort the data by a certain parameter. That is when pagination actually makes sense, otherwise, Django doesn't know what data to return and it would be replicated around requests.

So, in the first line, you need to do:

`trainers_list = Profile.objects.filter(city__slug = slug).order_by('x')`

Here `x` is an attribute for `Profile` object on the basis of which you can actually sort data.

Comment: Adding a sort has no effect

Comment: What is the parameter you're using in the sort? Is it unique across the Profile objects?

Comment: I tried to use diffirent fields include unique. Django documentation does not have any instructions for sorting for pagination

Comment: When you order something, then only it is guaranteed that the queryset gives you unique results on each page. Can you please tell me what is the exact field you're adding sorting for?

Comment: **slug** - unique for each objects and **price** - not unique

Comment: You need something other than slug or price. Something that is quantitative enough to distinguish the results.

Maybe you can use `created_at` timestamp when you don't have any other attribute that fits the need. I'm pretty confident, it would work. Can you please try and let me know?

Comment: Yes I use such a field, I have it called add_date. But it did not work

Comment: What is the query now and what does the end result look like?

Comment: `trainers_list = Profile.objects.filter(city__slug = slug).order_by('add_date')` The result  is same like a question